# AC motor design

Tags: motor, ac, stator

[image]
Is it possible to have an AC motor with only a partial stator, one that does not fully encompass the rotor? Refer to the picture to understand what I mean. This would be needed to drive a spherical tire of a car.

Comment: The simplest AC motor demonstrated in physical experiments is a wire frame between two permanent magnets. Pretty much fitting the description.

Comment: Yes. It should be possible. Afterall, there is such a thing as a linear motor.

Comment: Maybe an axial flux motor with a caliper type stator.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible - I built one many years ago to allow a cutaway model of a power tool to run. Bear in mind that a C shaped stator would produce significant radial forces on the rotor shaft if you're trying to produce a lot of power with it, and having two opposing sections of stator, i.e. with a symmetrical gap on opposite sides would balance out the radial forces - but reduce the amount of power you could produce for a given motor size.

Comment: Axial flux might be better, if it is a clean sheet design.

Comment: Even with axial flux there'd still be a resultant radial load from asymmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although getting efficiency out of it may be quite difficult.  Conceptually, you may want to start with linear motors, and go from there.